# AngularJS - add HTML element to dom in directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive in which I  add a `<div class="perc"></div>`

From what for it happens?

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log('scope', scope, elem, attrs);
                var t = elem[0];
                var dataperc = attrs.perc,
                    barperc = Math.round(dataperc * 5.56),
                    bar = elem.children()[0],
                    label = elem.children()[2];
                bar.animate({width: barperc}, dataperc * 25);
                label.append('<div class="perc"></div>');
                $compile(elem)(scope);

                function perc() {
                    var length = bar.css('width'),
                        perc = Math.round(parseInt(length) / 5.56),
                        labelpos = (parseInt(length) - 2);
                    label.css('left', labelpos);
                    t.find('.perc').text(perc + '%');
                    console.log('perc',t, barperc, dataperc, length, perc, labelpos);

                }
            console.log(t, label, barperc, dataperc);

            perc();
            setInterval(perc, 0);

        }
```

but angular add like this

```
<div class="label">
    <span></span>
    <div class="perc"></div>
```

But I need to add it to the span

Comment: can you show us your html code where you're using the directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the `span` is inside your `label`, select the `span` and append your code into the `span`.

Refer code:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log('scope', scope, elem, attrs);
                var t = elem[0];
                var dataperc = attrs.perc,
                    barperc = Math.round(dataperc * 5.56),
                    bar = elem.children()[0],
                    label = elem.children()[2];
                bar.animate({width: barperc}, dataperc * 25);
                // change this line of code.
                label.find("span").append('<div class="perc"></div>');
                $compile(elem)(scope);

                function perc() {
                    var length = bar.css('width'),
                        perc = Math.round(parseInt(length) / 5.56),
                        labelpos = (parseInt(length) - 2);
                    label.css('left', labelpos);
                    t.find('.perc').text(perc + '%');
                    console.log('perc',t, barperc, dataperc, length, perc, labelpos);

                }
            console.log(t, label, barperc, dataperc);

            perc();
            setInterval(perc, 0);

        }
```

Since, `span` is the first level children of `label`, you can also use:

```
label.children("span").append('<div class="perc"></div>');
```

Also, try the following:

```
label.firstElementChild.append('<div class="perc"></div>');
```

Comment: TypeError: label.children is not a function

Comment: Are you using jQuery here, or is it pure javascript elements?

Comment: Yes, your last offer worked, thank you very much, 
Could you still help me? How do i refer to, 
var length = bar.css('width'), 
Failed to execute 'animate'

Comment: Maybe try `bar.animate({width: barperc}, parseInt(dataperc) * 25);`